# Creating an Estimate in QBO Gives Error about LineDetail Type

Tags: c#, quickbooks-online

I am creating an estimate in QBO using the C# SDK. I am getting an error about LineDetail type not being included. Here's the JSON we are posting:

```
{"CustomerRef":{"value":"137"},
"CurrencyRef":{"value":"USD"},
"Line":[{"Description":"Roof - B1-011900908","Amount":527.48,"DetailType":"SalesOrderItemLineDetail","SalesItemLineDetail":{"Qty":1.0}}]}
```

I am getting this error

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Required param missing, need to supply the required value for the API","Detail":"Required parameter Line.DetailType is missing in the request","code":"2020","element":"Line.DetailType"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2019-12-09T12:38:25.648-08:00"}
```

Comment: I believe this `"DetailType":"SalesOrderItemLineDetail"` should be `"DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail"`

Comment: Yea it is, add an answer and I'll give you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting an error about LineDetail type not being included. Here's the JSON we are posting

```
{"CustomerRef":{"value":"137"},
"CurrencyRef":{"value":"USD"},
"Line":[{"Description":"Roof - B1-011900908","Amount":527.48,"DetailType":"SalesOrderItemLineDetail","SalesItemLineDetail":{"Qty":1.0}}]}
```

The parameter name and value for `DetailType` is:

```
 "DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line object I had

```
DetailType=LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesOrderItemLineDetail
```

Should have been:

```
DetailType=LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail
```